# Save an order from admin without submitting - quotation

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status, edit-order

Can I save an order from admin without submitting? So without triggering the payment logics?

I want to create an internal management of quotation that could then become orders. An idea is to not use custom entities, because any change to the Magento order entity would mean making a change to the Custom Quotation entity. I need a way to save an order from Admin, with status: "Quotation" that does not trigger all the payment logic (maybe even remove Invoice and Shipping, but maybe that's just a matter of raising the blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Not easily no. My best advice is to go down extension route

https://www.cart2quote.com/

Is one I know and have used. Cheapest version has encrypted source code though which is a put off. But is feature rich and there as a more expensive edition which is open source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know this module but it is not for us, also because it is encrypted and therefore does not lend itself to customization. We would like to avoid developing any order-related logic twice, then 1: on order 2: on the quote.

I will try to bang my head on this solution :)